# Is there an elegant way of having multiple obligatory if in one function

Tags: c

I am implementing the Midpoint circle algorithm in C: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C
For my program, the user mention the starting point and its radius. We can provide it with a negative starting point but not a negative radius. Therefore I need to check if we will draw outside of its designed area. That's where this code:

```
    int f = 1 - radius;
    int ddF_x = 0;
    int ddF_y = -2 * radius;
    int x = 0;
    int y = radius;

    plot(x0, y0 + radius);
    plot(x0, y0 - radius);
    plot(x0 + radius, y0);
    plot(x0 - radius, y0);

    while(x < y) 
    {
        if(f >= 0) 
        {
            y--;
            ddF_y += 2;
            f += ddF_y;
        }
        x++;
        ddF_x += 2;
        f += ddF_x + 1;    
        plot(x0 + x, y0 + y);
        plot(x0 - x, y0 + y);
        plot(x0 + x, y0 - y);
        plot(x0 - x, y0 - y);
        plot(x0 + y, y0 + x);
        plot(x0 - y, y0 + x);
        plot(x0 + y, y0 - x);
        plot(x0 - y, y0 - x);
    }
}
```

Will then be:

```
        int x0 = values_c[0], y0 = values_c[1], radius = values_c[2];
        int f = 1 - radius; 
        int ddF_x = 0, ddF_y = -2 * radius;
        int x = 0;
        if (isInCanvas(x0, y0 + radius)) { mainCanvas->pixels[x0][y0 + radius] = mainCanvas->pen; }
        if (isInCanvas(x0, y0 - radius)) { mainCanvas->pixels[x0][y0 - radius] = mainCanvas->pen; }
        if (isInCanvas(x0 + radius, y0)) { mainCanvas->pixels[x0 + radius][y0] = mainCanvas->pen; }
        if (isInCanvas(x0 - radius, y0)) { mainCanvas->pixels[x0 - radius][y0] = mainCanvas->pen; }

        while (x < radius)
        {
            if (f >= 0)
            {
                radius--;
                ddF_y += 2;
                f += ddF_y;
            }
            x++;
            ddF_x += 2;
            f += ddF_x + 1;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 + x, y0 + radius))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 + x][y0 + radius] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 - x, y0 + radius))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 - x][y0 + radius] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 + x, y0 - radius))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 + x][y0 - radius] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 - x, y0 - radius))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 - x][y0 - radius] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 + radius, y0 + x))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 + radius][y0 + x] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 - radius, y0 + x))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 - radius][y0 + x] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 + radius, y0 - x))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 + radius][y0 - x] = mainCanvas->pen;
            if (isInCanvas(x0 - radius, y0 - x))mainCanvas->pixels[x0 - radius][y0 - x] = mainCanvas->pen;
        }
```

So im not drawing outside of the designated area of `mainCanvas`. 
Would there by any more elegant way of checking if `isInCanvas` is true before drawing every point?

Comment: Sounds like you need a draw function you can apply a clipping mask to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the check in the `plot()` function:

```
function plot(x, y) {
    if (isInCanvas(x, y) {
        mainCanvas->pixels[x][y] = mainCanvas->pen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I also need to pass ```mainCanvas``` as an argument to ```plot``` in C?

Comment: From the code you posted I couldn't tell what's local and global. If that's a local variable you'll need to pass it.